# Загрузка файла через Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, upload

Сделал [такой пример](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-upload-file-ajax-jquery-formdata/).

Но когда я пытаюсь загрузить второй файл, удалив перед этим старый `img` тег, картинка не обновляется. Почему-то не вызывается метод `get` в классе `RestController`.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: покажите свой код

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Сейчас нет возможности просто код предоставить - на работе.

Comment: А так в этом примере из метода get спрингового контроллера возвращается
"<img src='http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-file-upload/rest/cont/get/"+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+"' />";

Comment: И мне непонятно, почему когда я во второй раз загружаю другое изображение, то картинка не обновляется а остается первое изображение

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что картинка кэшируется в браузере. Попробуйте добавить какой-нибудь произвольный параметр к ссылке на картинку и подставлять например текущее значение миллисекунд. Хотя конечно лучше было бы более подробно писать вопрос - я исключительно на интуицию опираюсь, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: Да, извиняюсь. нужно мне было свой код вставить. Я возвращаю : 
"<img src='http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-file-upload/rest/cont/get/val' />"
Т.е. без Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
Проверю это. спасибо